# How to target a div beside the sidebar so that it will push the div to the left when the sidebar opens

Tags: javascript, html, css

Whenever I open my sidebar, the main-content div goes under the sidebar instead of pushing it to the right and the px of the div should be equivalent to the width of the sidebar when it shows up. I wrote a css and js function and its still not working.

The problem is here, maybe im not targeting the correct div. or maybe im missing a css property when i wrote the styling. hope u can help me guys, giving me a link to a documentation or an article with the same problem will be a great help for me and for my growth. Thanks

```js
const menuLink = document.querySelector('.dashboard-nav-links li:nth-child(3) a');
const navbar = document.querySelector('.dashboard-navbar');
const navItemToggle = document.querySelector('.nav-item-toggle');

menuLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbar.classList.toggle('menu-open');
  if (navbar.classList.contains('menu-open')) {
    menuLink.innerHTML = 'CLOSE';
    navItemToggle.style.backgroundColor = '#F1B24B'; // Add background color
  } else {
    menuLink.innerHTML = '<i class="bi bi-list"></i>MENU';
    menuLink.style.color = '#000000'; // Set font color back to black
    navItemToggle.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent'; // Remove background color
  }
});

const navToggle = document.querySelector('.nav-item-toggle a');
const sidebar = document.querySelector('.dashboard-sidebar-nav');
const mainDiv = document.querySelector('.main-content');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close-btn');


function toggleSidebar() {
  sidebar.classList.toggle('show');
  mainDiv.classList.toggle('sidebar-open');
}

function moveMainContentRight() {
  mainContent.style.marginLeft = '300px';
}

function moveMainContentLeft() {
  mainContent.style.marginLeft = '0';
}

// Event listeners
navToggle.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  toggleSidebar();
});
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleSidebar);
```

```css
.dashboard-navbar {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 11.88em;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #F1B24B;
}

.dashboard-nav-links {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-family: 'Urbanist';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 38px;
  color: #000000;
}

.dashboard-nav-links .nav-item a {
  font-size: 23px;
  color: #000000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.dashboard-nav-links li {
  margin-right: -20px;
  color: #000000 !important;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.nav-item-toggle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 223px;
  height: 11.90em;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #262626;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 1;
}

ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top: 2px solid #174A41;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #174A41;
  transform: scaleY(2);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

ul li a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #262626;
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  z-index: -1;
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #174A41;
}

@keyframes grow {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

ul li a:hover:before {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-item-toggle a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.dashboard-sidebar-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 414px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #F1B24B;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -414px;
  transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out;
  margin-top: 165px;
}

.dashboard-sidebar-nav.show {
  left: 0;
}

.dashboard-sidebar-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.dashboard-sidebar-nav ul li {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.dashboard-sidebar-nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.hide-menu {
  margin-top: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header class="dashboard-navbar">
  <div class="logo">

    <span style="font-family: 'Urbanist'; font-weight: 900; font-size:24px; color: 
    #000000">STATE UNIVERSITY</span>
  </div>
  <ul class="dashboard-nav-links">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">UNIVERSITY SITE</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">MY PROFILE</a></li>
    <li class='nav-item-toggle'>
      <a href="#" style="color:#000000; font-size: 32px;">
        <i class="bi bi-list"></i>MENU</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>

<div class="dashboard-sidebar">
  <nav class="dashboard-sidebar-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Enrollment</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">My Checklist</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">University Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="hide-menu">
      <a href="#">Hide Menu</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class='main-content'>
  <h2>What is my enrollment status?</h2>
  <i class="bi bi-check"></i>
  <p>Approved</p>

  <h2>What do you need?</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `left: -414px;` in your `.dashboard-sidebar-nav` class. Then your `.dashboard-sidebar-nav.show` have `left: 0;` that means the *sidebar* will toggle on the left side.

I made some revision on your work.

```js
const menuLink = document.querySelector('.dashboard-nav-links li:nth-child(3) a');
const navbar = document.querySelector('.dashboard-navbar');
const navItemToggle = document.querySelector('.nav-item-toggle');

menuLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbar.classList.toggle('menu-open');
  if (navbar.classList.contains('menu-open')) {
    menuLink.innerHTML = 'CLOSE';
    navItemToggle.style.backgroundColor = '#F1B24B'; // Add background color
  } else {
    menuLink.innerHTML = '<i class="bi bi-list"></i>MENU';
    menuLink.style.color = '#000000'; // Set font color back to black
    navItemToggle.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent'; // Remove background color
  }
});

const navToggle = document.querySelector('.nav-item-toggle a');
const sidebar = document.querySelector('.dashboard-sidebar-nav');
const mainDiv = document.querySelector('.main-content');
const closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close-btn');


function toggleSidebar() {
  sidebar.classList.toggle('show');
  mainDiv.classList.toggle('sidebar-open');
}

function moveMainContentRight() {
  mainContent.style.marginLeft = '300px';
}

function moveMainContentLeft() {
  mainContent.style.marginLeft = '0';
}

// Event listeners
navToggle.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  toggleSidebar();
});
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleSidebar);
```

```css
.dashboard-navbar {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 11.88em;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #F1B24B;
}

.dashboard-nav-links {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-family: 'Urbanist';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 38px;
  color: #000000;
}

.dashboard-nav-links .nav-item a {
  font-size: 23px;
  color: #000000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.dashboard-nav-links li {
  margin-right: -20px;
  color: #000000 !important;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.nav-item-toggle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 223px;
  height: 11.90em;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #262626;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 1;
}

ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top: 2px solid #174A41;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #174A41;
  transform: scaleY(2);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

ul li a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #262626;
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  z-index: -1;
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #174A41;
}

@keyframes grow {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

ul li a:hover:before {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-item-toggle a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.dashboard-sidebar-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 414px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #F1B24B;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  /* left: -414px; */
  right: -414px;
  /* transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out; */
  transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
  margin-top: 165px;
}

.dashboard-sidebar-nav.show {
  /* left: 0; */
  right: 8px;
}

.dashboard-sidebar-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.dashboard-sidebar-nav ul li {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.dashboard-sidebar-nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.hide-menu {
  margin-top: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header class="dashboard-navbar">
  <div class="logo">

    <span style="font-family: 'Urbanist'; font-weight: 900; font-size:24px; color: 
    #000000">STATE UNIVERSITY</span>
  </div>
  <ul class="dashboard-nav-links">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">UNIVERSITY SITE</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">MY PROFILE</a></li>
    <li class='nav-item-toggle'>
      <a href="#" style="color:#000000; font-size: 32px;">
        <i class="bi bi-list"></i>MENU</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>

<div class="dashboard-sidebar">
  <nav class="dashboard-sidebar-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Enrollment</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">My Checklist</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">University Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="hide-menu">
      <a href="#">Hide Menu</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class='main-content'>
  <h2>What is my enrollment status?</h2>
  <i class="bi bi-check"></i>
  <p>Approved</p>

  <h2>What do you need?</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: bro u moved the sidebar to the right, anyway i fixed it already.